# Generic argument list for an exec task?

Tags: nant

At the moment I've got several tasks that contain an exec task (SqlCmd). These all use the same argument list (username, options, etc) with only the executed script changing.

Is there a way to create a generic list of arguments, like you can with filter chain? eg:

```
<filterchain refid="AllProperties" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a task that has the exec with all arguments -- either values or NAnt properties, then `<call target="TheExecTask" />` in the places you want to use it.  Note that `call` resets the depends list, so make this task depend on nothing and carefully document that this is a utility function not a regular task.